# libssh2.so.1cannot open shared object file?

Tags: linux, installation, security, installer, compile

I am trying to run medusa program when I have run it with command `medusa -d` I got

```
+ cvs.mod : Couldn't load "/usr/local/lib/medusa/modules/cvs.mod" [libssh2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
    + ftp.mod : Couldn't load "/usr/local/lib/medusa/modules/ftp.mod" [libssh2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
    + http.mod : Couldn't load "/usr/local/lib/medusa/modules/http.mod" [libssh2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
    + imap.mod : Couldn't load "/usr/local/lib/medusa/modules/imap.mod" [libssh2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
    + mssql.mod : Couldn't load "/usr/local/lib/medusa/modules/mssql.mod" [libssh2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
    + mysql.mod : Couldn't load "/usr/local/lib/medusa/modules/mysql.mod" [libssh2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
    + nntp.mod : Couldn't load "/usr/local/lib/medusa/modules/nntp.mod" [libssh2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
    + pcanywhere.mod : Couldn't load "/usr/local/lib/medusa/modules/pcanywhere.mod" [libssh2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
    + pop3.mod : Couldn't load "/usr/local/lib/medusa/modules/pop3.mod" [libssh2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
    + postgres.mod : Couldn't load "/usr/local/lib/medusa/modules/postgres.mod" [libssh2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
    + rexec.mod : Couldn't load "/usr/local/lib/medusa/modules/rexec.mod" [libssh2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
    + rlogin.mod : Couldn't load "/usr/local/lib/medusa/modules/rlogin.mod" [libssh2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
    + rsh.mod : Couldn't load "/usr/local/lib/medusa/modules/rsh.mod" [libssh2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
    + smbnt.mod : Couldn't load "/usr/local/lib/medusa/modules/smbnt.mod" [libssh2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
    + smtp-vrfy.mod : Couldn't load "/usr/local/lib/medusa/modules/smtp-vrfy.mod" [libssh2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
    + smtp.mod : Couldn't load "/usr/local/lib/medusa/modules/smtp.mod" [libssh2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
    + snmp.mod : Couldn't load "/usr/local/lib/medusa/modules/snmp.mod" [libssh2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
    + SSH.mod : Couldn't load "/usr/local/lib/medusa/modules/SSH.mod" [libssh2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
    + telnet.mod : Couldn't load "/usr/local/lib/medusa/modules/telnet.mod" [libssh2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
    + vmauthd.mod : Couldn't load "/usr/local/lib/medusa/modules/vmauthd.mod" [libssh2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
    + vnc.mod : Couldn't load "/usr/local/lib/medusa/modules/vnc.mod" [libssh2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
    + web-form.mod : Couldn't load "/usr/local/lib/medusa/modules/web-form.mod" [libssh2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
    + wrapper.mod : Couldn't load "/usr/local/lib/medusa/modules/wrapper.mod" [libssh2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
loft1034:~#
```

what is the problem please ?

Answer (score 3):

`wget` the Medusa version like I'm using 1.4, then

```
tar zxvf 
.configure
make
make install
```

If it gives you an error with `make install`, first run `su root`, then run `make install`. This should work now. You might face problems with `ssh.mod` – then download:

```
wget http://www.libssh2.org/download/libssh2-1.2.6.tar.gz
```

And it should be fine. You might need to `mv` or create a new path. If it gives you errors with `medusa -d`, this means something was wrong with the downloaded version.

For example, by default, mine shows you something like:

```
~/medusa-1.4 $ medusa -d

Medusa v1.4 [http://www.foofus.net] (C) JoMo-Kun / Foofus Networks <jmk@foofus.net>

  Available modules in "." :

  Available modules in "/usr/local/lib/medusa/modules" :
    + cvs.mod : Brute force module for CVS sessions : version 1.0.0
    + ftp.mod : Brute force module for FTP/FTPS sessions : version 1.3.0
    + http.mod : Brute force module for HTTP : version 1.3.0
    + imap.mod : Brute force module for IMAP sessions : version 1.1.0
    + mssql.mod : Brute force module for M$-SQL sessions : version 1.1.1
    + mysql.mod : Brute force module for MySQL sessions : version 1.2
    + nntp.mod : Brute force module for NNTP sessions : version 0.9
    + pcanywhere.mod : Brute force module for PcAnywhere sessions : version 1.0.2
    + pop3.mod : Brute force module for POP3 sessions : version 1.1.1
    + postgres.mod : Brute force module for PostgreSQL sessions : version 1.0.0
    + rexec.mod : Brute force module for REXEC sessions : version 1.1.1
    + rlogin.mod : Brute force module for RLOGIN sessions : version 1.0.2
    + rsh.mod : Brute force module for RSH sessions : version 1.0.1
    + smbnt.mod : Brute force module for SMB/NTLMv1 sessions : version 1.3.1
    + smtp-vrfy.mod : Brute force module for enumerating accounts via SMTP VRFY : version 0.9.1
    + snmp.mod : Brute force module for SNMP Community Strings : version 1.0.0
    + svn.mod : Brute force module for Subversion sessions : version 1.0.0
    + telnet.mod : Brute force module for telnet sessions : version 1.2.1
    + vmauthd.mod : Brute force module for the VMware Authentication Daemon : version 1.0.0
    + vnc.mod : Brute force module for VNC sessions : version 1.0.1
    + wrapper.mod : Generic Wrapper Module : version 1.0.1
```